# Get cookies from a third-party site by sending login information using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, cookie, api

I have a website (ASP.NET) which also provides an API. But to access it, it requires login.

I want to connect to this site with javascript, 'send' the user credentials to it and receive the cookies (ASP.NET_SessionID and ASPXAUTH) to use them for API calls. But I don't know how to do it.

I already did it with Java though but I have too little experience with javascript. I heard maybe I could do it with cURL?

Comment: cURL is a command line program so it won't help you from a browser using JavaScript.

Comment: I think it might be possible using AJAX because you can see the response headers, one of which is cookies.   See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header